# Linearly extending a planar rotation to a spatial rotation

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, finite-groups, linear-transformations, orthonormal

I'm currently reading the book "Finite Reflection Groups" by Grove and Benson for a kind of undergraduate course the Germans call "Proseminar" - it basically means I have to read up on a topic which to then give a presentation on. However, one particular paragraph in this book gets me stumped - I'm not sure whether I've stumbled upon a mistake in the book or whether I'm mistaken about this. On page 11, the last paragraph reads as follows:

> Suppose that $\dim V=3$ and that $W$ is a plane in $V$, i.e., a subspace of dimension $2$. If $R$ is a rotation in $\mathcal O(W)$, then $R$ may be extended to a rotation in $\mathcal O(V)$ if we set $Rx=x$ for all $x\in W^\perp$ and extend by linearity. If a basis $\{x_1,x_2,x_3\}$ is chosen for $V$, with $x_1\in W^\perp,x_2,x_3\in W$, then the matrix representing $R$ is
>
> $A=\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0\\0&\cos\theta&-\sin\theta\\0&\sin\theta&\cos\theta\end{bmatrix}$.

So my question is - do not we have to assume that the aforementioned basis is an orthonormal basis? (Of course, from the definition, $x_1$ is perpendicular to the other two vectors but I don't see why we need not assume that these are unit vectors and that $x_2\perp x_3$?) Hope, someone can point me in the right way if there's a detail I'm too blind to see.

Comment: Yep. You're correct. But if you pick a basis, you can always apply gram-schmidt to $x_2$ and $x_3$ to make them orthonormal, so it's not a big deal. To convince yourself you're correct, look at the $xy$-plane, and rotation by 90 degrees. Pick $x_2$ to be $(1,0,0)$ and $x_3 = (1, 1,0)$, and $x_1 = (0,0,1)$. Then the matrix you get doesnt' have that form at all.